# Google Scripts not skipping rows

Tags: google-apps-script

Pretty new to using google scripts, so forgive me if I'm doing something silly.

I am trying to write a program to take a large spreadsheet of data and fill an invoice template I have created.  I have successfully done this in the past, but now when I tried to apply the app to a new spreadsheet of data, it is no longer functioning properly.

The problem is because the sheet is so large, the scripts times out, then when I go to restart the script, it starts again all the way at the beginning instead of starting where it left off.  Originally the function was set to write the URL of the new invoice in the last column of spreadsheet, and the function would skip any rows with entries in that column.  This was not happening, so to simplify I added another row that once the invoice is created, the word "DONE" is entered, and then I tried to set it up to skip any row with "DONE" in that column, this still is not working.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
}
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
//This value should be the id of your document template that we created in the last step
const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1yXfcXTESCHqKsfMcgkhYJ9MdVwYoLYPhH1MRv4RyPk0');
  //This value should be the id of the folder where you want your completed documents stored
const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1TXEumNJXfgFzPtKLBOAKJBXG-yNnjseQ')
//Here we store the sheet as a variable
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp
.getActiveSpreadsheet()
.getSheetByName('Export Worksheet')
 //Now we get all of the values as a 2D array
const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
//Start processing each spreadsheet row
rows.forEach(function(row, index){
//Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
if (index === 0) return;
//Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if so we skip it
if (row[31]=== 'DONE') return;
//Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our destinationFolder
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[4]}, ${row[0]} Invoice` , destinationFolder)
//Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp

const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
//All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
const body = doc.getBody();
//In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();

 //In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
body.replaceText('{{Full Address}}', row[4]);
body.replaceText('{{unit}}', row[5]);
body.replaceText('{{Total}}', row[15]);
body.replaceText('{{Account Num}}', row[2]);
body.replaceText('{{Owner 1}}', row[6]);
body.replaceText('{{Owner 2}}', row[7]);
body.replaceText('{{CO Name}}', row[17]);
body.replaceText('{{St Address}}', row[20]);
body.replaceText('{{Address 1}}', row[18]);
body.replaceText('{{City}}', row[21]);
body.replaceText('{{State}}', row[22]);
body.replaceText('{{CO Zip}}', row[23]);
body.replaceText('{{invoice #}}', row[0]);

//We make our changes permanent by saving and closing the document
doc.saveAndClose();
//Store the url of our new document in a variable
const url = doc.getUrl();
//Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 30).setValue(url)
//Write that value back to the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet. 
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 31).setValue("DONE")
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You were checking for DONE in the wrong location

```
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1yXfc...');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1TXE...');
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Export Worksheet');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[30] != 'DONE') {
      const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${r[4]}, ${r[0]} Invoice`, destinationFolder);
      const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
      const body = doc.getBody();
      body.replaceText('{{Full Address}}', r[4]);
      body.replaceText('{{unit}}', r[5]);
      body.replaceText('{{Total}}', r[15]);
      body.replaceText('{{Account Num}}', r[2]);
      body.replaceText('{{Owner 1}}', r[6]);
      body.replaceText('{{Owner 2}}', r[7]);
      body.replaceText('{{CO Name}}', r[17]);
      body.replaceText('{{St Address}}', r[20]);
      body.replaceText('{{Address 1}}', r[18]);
      body.replaceText('{{City}}', r[21]);
      body.replaceText('{{State}}', r[22]);
      body.replaceText('{{CO Zip}}', r[23]);
      body.replaceText('{{invoice #}}', r[0]);
      doc.saveAndClose();
      const url = doc.getUrl();
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 30).setValue(url);
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 31).setValue("DONE");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! My problem is solved, appreciate your help!